# Correct use of IAsyncEnumerable in EF Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-core

What is the correct way to perform a query in Entity Framework Core that returns the data as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

I've come to the conclusion I should return data from a query as an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` from the following StackOverflow posts:

1. Stephen Cleary (.NET async guru) advising to use async methods where possible, when asked about using async vs sync methods in EF Core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62313515/216440
2. An answer to the StackOverflow question "Should I return Task<IEnumerable> or IAsyncEnumerable from repository?" says a general rule of thumb is to stream (ie return `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`) if there is no particular need to buffer (ie return `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748549/216440

Okay, my query should return `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` but how should I do that?

The MS EF Core documentation about [avoiding DbContext threading issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#avoiding-dbcontext-threading-issues) says:

> Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance.

and, as a result

> Always await EF Core asynchronous methods immediately.

I tried the following:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager> GetEmployeeManagerByCompanyAsync(int companyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var employeeManagers = await _dbContext.EmployeePosition
        .Where(ep => ep.CompanyId == companyId)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeManager(ep.EmployeeId, ep.ManagerId))
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();

    return employeeManagers;
}
```

This gives a compiler error `'IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148747/216440) StackOverflow answer suggests to fix this I should do the following:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager> GetEmployeeManagerByCompanyAsync(int companyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var employeeManagers = _dbContext.EmployeePosition
        .Where(ep => ep.CompanyId == companyId)
        .Where(ep => !ep.Deleted)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeManager(ep.EmployeeId, ep.ManagerId))
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();       

    await foreach(var employeeManager in employeeManagers)
    {
        yield return employeeManager;
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the compiler errors but it seems a bit long-winded to have to iterate over the query results just to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.  Is there a better way of returning the results of a query as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: When dealing with an RDBMS, there is less utility in using `IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager>` because your queries will be returning a single batch (i.e. a `List<T>`) per query where there's no real benefit to treating each individual row as a separate asynchronously-loaded item (and in-fact, because TDS transfers data in batches anyway, doing so is only adding overhead for no gain at all). IMO, `IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager>` only makes sense for things like an Rx `Observable<T>` or `Subject<T>` - or an endless SSE stream - but we have `Channel<T>` for that already...

Comment: ...the other major legitimate use-case for `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` would be when `T` itself is a batch - so if you're reading from a data-source of unknown (or truly massive) total size - but with fixed-size pages or batches, then it makes sense to return `IAsyncEnumerable<PagedList<T>>`, where `PagedList<T>` is a `List<T>` with added paging parameters (offset/pageIndex, pageSize, anchor, etc).

Comment: Do note that the context needs to be disposed as it manages the connection, and therefore if you are returning the resultset back to a client over HTTP then you need a way of ensuring it's disposed, usually by using DI. This is more of a problem using `IAsyncEnumerable` because you are returning the *promise* of a resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IAsyncEnumerable<T>` would not be used in conjunction with an `async` method. It is used internally within `ToListAsync<T>()` etc to serve `await`/`async` so returning `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` would be:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeManager> GetEmployeeManagerByCompanyAsync(int companyId)
{
    var employeeManagers = _dbContext.EmployeePosition
        .Where(ep => ep.CompanyId == companyId)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeManager(ep.EmployeeId, ep.ManagerId))
        .AsAsyncEnumerable();

    return employeeManagers;
}
```

Any checks around a cancellation token would occur within consuming the async enumerable. Making it `async` would just be:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EmployeeManager>> GetEmployeeManagerByCompanyAsync(int companyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var employeeManagers = await _dbContext.EmployeePosition
        .Where(ep => ep.CompanyId == companyId)
        .Select(ep => new EmployeeManager(ep.EmployeeId, ep.ManagerId))
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    return employeeManagers;
}
```

... which would incorporate the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` internally.

I do not recommend bastardizing the entity to represent a partially filled container: `.Select(ep => new EmployeeManager(ep.EmployeeId, ep.ManagerId))` Either return the entities or return a dedicated cut down summary DTO. The main reason to avoid cutting down and passing incomplete detached entities as partial wrappers for data is to avoid confusion when you may have functions that expect an EmployeeManager but could be passed actual tracked or detached EmployeeManagers or cut down EmployeeManager instances that just contain these two IDs. If you want to pass complete instances that are not tracked/cached by the DbContext, use `AsNoTracking()` rather than new-ing up a copy to avoid introducing bugs with incomplete data.

Comment: Thanks.  In each of the two methods you provided how would you handle the `cancellationToken`?  In the second one it could be passed to `ToListAsync()` I assume.  How about the first one?  As far as I can see `AsAsyncEnumerable()` doesn't take a cancellation token parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify: `EmployeeManager` only has the two properties, `EmployeeId` and `ManagerId`.  The real class name is `EmployeeManagerCompact`.  I just shortened the name to simplify the code sample in the question.  I can see now perhaps I shouldn't have done that.  Still worthwhile advice about avoiding partially-filled objects, however.

Comment: I corrected the example with `ToListAsync()` to include the cancellation token. For the AsAsyncEnumerable you would handle the cancellation token externally when iterating the enumerable similar to how you did in your expanded example with the yield. Check the cancellation token within the iteration, so AFAIK it wouldn't need to be passed into that method in that case.  Sounds like the EmployeeManager(Compact) is effectively a DTO rather than Entity so all good there.